# What does this piece of code do? Accessing struct via index?

Tags: c

I am currently studying the LLVM compiler. In their language reference (http://llvm.org/releases/3.7.0/docs/LangRef.html#getelementptr-instruction) they give some C code as an example for a getelementptr instruction. But I don't understand how this code can even work.

```
struct RT {
  char A;
  int B[10][20];
  char C;
};

struct ST {
  int X;
  double Y;
  struct RT Z;
};

int *foo(struct ST *s) {
  return &s[1].Z.B[5][13];
}
```

What does `s[1]` do here?

Is it accessing the struct with an index?

How does it get the element Z here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any pointer, `struct ST *` in this case, can be treated as a pointer to an array.  By writing `s[1]` the programmer is assuming that `foo` receives an array of at least two `struct ST` objects.  (If the programmer is wrong about that, the program has undefined behavior.)

So, `s[1]` accesses the second element of the array pointed-to by `S`.  That element is a `struct ST`, so `.Z` accesses its `Z` field, which is a `struct RT`. `.B` reaches inside `struct RT` for the `B` field, which is a two-dimensional array, and finally `[5][13]` index a specific integer in that array.

The `&` operator is evaluated *after* all of these operations, and retrieves the address of that specific integer, which is the result of the function.

I am not familiar with LLVM's intermediate representation, but `getelementptr` sounds like a plausible name for an IR operator that implements a chain of indexing and field accesses and returns a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`s` is of type `struct ST *`, a pointer to `struct ST`. Arrays and pointers are more or less the same thing in C (with some caveats). So `s[1]` is a `struct ST`.

`.Z` accesses the element `Z` therein, which is `struct RT`. `.B` accesses the element `B` in that struct, and then we take the `[5][13]` element of that, and finally use `&` to return the address of that element.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it accessing the struct with an index?

No. `struct ST *s` : s is a pointer, so it might be pointing to some array of elements of type `ST`.

`s[1]` gets the second element of such an array. `s[1]` is equivalent to `(*(s+1))`.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have `struct ST *s`, we also know that s[1] is of type `struct ST`. It's simply treating `s` as the pointer to the first element of an array-of-struct-S.